# Firefox full screen flickers to previous window when adjusting volume

Tags: firefox, fullscreen, flicker

This bug occurs whenever I am in full screen in Firefox, streaming something on YouTube or other sites.

When I adjust the volume and the gray notification in the middle of the screen (the one that displays the current volume level) disappears, more than half the time I get a brief glimpse of the previous opened window (it usually being the other Firefox window I have open, but this has occured with windows of other applications as well). It's not exactly a flicker, as it's not repeated and happens once per volume change, more of a split-second flash or glimpse. I've also noticed that this isn't exclusive to the volume notification, pretty much anything that interrupts the full screen in some way produces this bug. For example, the labels that appear when you flash over elements of a video player (the ones that show said elements name) also trigger this behaviour.

I can't seem to find a solution for this online and while this is not a system-breaking bug, it's incredibly annoying as I watch a lot of things during the day, most often in full screen. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem along with some screen tearing. 
For me the solution was to:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

And paste the following content in this configuration file

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Note that this is with an intel graphics card and may not work with others

Comment: I've never used Vim before, what do I do after pasting?

Comment: after pasting the text in the config file you should just reboot. This was enough for me. (the text editor doesn't really matter, if you prefer you can use nano or gedit)